# SqLite-WebSQL select and add to leaflet map as geojson layer

Tags: javascript, sqlite, leaflet, geojson, spatialite

I tried to save data using SqLite-WebSql and JavaScript to save polygon geometry in wkt format. So far I have managed to save data with the following script:

```
    var db = openDatabase("spatial", "1.0", "local spatial data", 32678);

    // Create geodata table if required
    db.transaction(function(transaction){
      transaction.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS geodata (" +
        "fid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        "geom TEXT NOT NULL, type TEXT NOT NULL);");
    });

    var wkt = 'POLYGON((120.102539 -2.471157,121.003418 -1.878326,121.92627 -2.822346,120.563965 -3.787522,120.102539 -2.471157))';
    var type = 'POLYGON';

    saveDb(wkt,type);

    var saveDb = function(geom, type, successCallback){
      db.transaction(function(transaction){
        transaction.executeSql(("INSERT INTO geodata (geom, type) VALUES (?, ?);"), 
        [geom, type]);
      });
    };
```

Then I save one more row of additional data and the results are as follows:

```
id | fid |                                                    geom                                                              | type
 1 |  1  | POLYGON((120.102539 -2.471157,121.003418 -1.878326,121.92627 -2.822346,120.563965 -3.787522,120.102539 -2.471157))   | POLYGON
 2 |  2  | POLYGON((121.311035 -2.975956,122.145996 -2.537012,122.651369 -3.655964,121.750488 -4.247814,121.311035 -2.975956))  | POLYGON
```

The question is how do I select table and generate geojson, then add them to leaflet map as the geojson layer.